# Changing log level for child modules, given parent

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

Is there a way to change the change the logging level of a child given only the parent?  I'm looking into doing something like this, but it seems there must be a simpler way.

```
if args.debug:
    logging.getLogger('module1.child1').setLevel('DEBUG')
    logging.getLogger('module1.child2').setLevel('DEBUG')
    logging.getLogger('module2').setLevel('DEBUG')
```

Some imported modules have a different level, so I can't set the root logger.

Comment: Pretty sure you only need that last line